# I have a problem with ArrayList as a value of Hashtable

Tags: java

I have created these two data structures

```
private Vector<Hapsira> places;
private Hashtable<Klienti,ArrayList<Hapsira>> booking;

public void addPlace(Place h) throws RezervimiException{
    if(h == null){
        throw new RezervimiException("null");
    }

    for(int i=0;i<places.size();i++){
        if(places.get(i).equals(h)){
            throw new RezervimiException("exits");
        }
    }

    places.add(h);

}

public boolean hasBooking(){
    return places.size() > 0;
}

public Hapsira bookPlace(Client k) throws RezervimiException{
    Place h = null;

    if(hasBooking()){
        h = places.remove(0);
    }

    return h;
}
```

In this method i want to test if my hashtable contains the same clients if that is true then you add the place to arraylist value,if that is not true you add the list to hashmap.

But iam doing wrong when i add places , the size of booking hashtable is always 1

```
public void registerPlace(Client k,Place h) throws RezervimiException{
    ArrayList<Place> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if(booking.containsKey(k)){
        list.add(h);
    } else {
        booking.put(k, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you perhaps add an example of how you're testing the methods (and what the erroneous result is)? It'd make it easier to understand how these methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

> " the size of booking hashtable is always 1 "

This means the put method puts the value using the same key over and over in your `registerPlace` method.

2 things to check.

1. Whether you are passing the same `Client k` instance in your `registerPlace` method over different invocations. Print the value of k or debug & inspect the variable to check this.
2. Also when you use data structures which relies on keys, you should make sure [it follows this very important contract.](https://www.hidroh.com/2016/07/25/effective-java-hashcode-equals/) (if you have not already done so).

You can also read more about [using keys in a Map here](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/how-to-use-a-map-in-java)